# How to remove date from Google Search meta description?

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

How do I remove the date from google search meta description, please check below for further details:

[image]

Comment: Did you check my code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Works with 

#### Yoast SEO

To eliminate the date display on the [**Yoast SEO**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin add this to the theme’s `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_show_date_in_snippet_preview', false);
```

**OR**

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_show_date_in_snippet_preview', '__return_false' );
```

Would you please add above code in your active theme `functions.php` ?